# Engine RPM acting strange

Tags: honda, transmission, civic

I have a 2005 Honda Civic. When I shift manual transmission from 4th to 3rd, the engine revs up, but the RPM gauge drops to normal. It runs normally in the other gears.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: This sounds normal- changing down a gear should make the engine rev higher as the synchromesh comes into play when you raise the clutch pedal.